# Couldn't find Plan without an ID in subscription controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I attempt to run the code, I get the error above. 
This happen on my stripe payment form : 
Step 1: The user select a plan
Step 2: The user confirm the current plan
Step 3: The user pay for this plan 
The error come in the third step.

Here are the logs :

```
Started POST "/subscriptions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-27 08:03:57 +0200
Processing by SubscriptionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"8oQZ2GBhAcAmrDtfbH0SEmbjfzfO2+nfpUtpIySUyTQ=", "subscription"=>{"company"=>"", "adress"=>"", "city"=>"", "country"=>"", "postal_code"=>"", "phone"=>"", "plan_id"=>"52", "stripe_card_token"=>""}, "commit"=>"Terminer la commande"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Plan without an ID):
  app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:11:in `new'
```

Here is the subscription_controller.rb :

```
    require "stripe"
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
skip_before_action :set_plan, only: [:new, :create]

def new
    @titre = "Terminer la commande"
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build(:plan_id => params[:plan])
end

def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
        flash[:success] = 'Congrats'
        redirect_to nosformations_path
        else
        flash[:error] = "Error"
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end

private

def set_plan
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
end
```

Here's the model Subscription.rb :

```
    belongs_to :plan
belongs_to :user

validates_presence_of :plan_id
validates_presence_of :email
attr_accessible :name, :price, :old_price, :also, :type_of, :interval, :description, :plan_id, :company, :adress, :city, :country, :postal_code, :phone, :stripe_card_token, :coupon

attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

def save_with_payment
    if valid?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token, email: email)
        self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
        save!
    end
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Erreur Stripe lors de la création du profil client : #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "Le paiement a échoué. Merci de vérifier les paramètres de paiement."
    false
end
```

I am looking for a response for several hours without success...
Any idea ?

Comment: Try `plan = Plan.find(params[:subscription][:plan_id])` instead of `plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])`

Comment: Why is the verb POST for new action? Shouldn't it be for the CREATE action?

Comment: @dreamingblackcat yes, you are right it will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `new` action in `subscriptions_controller` change this line:

```
plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
```

to:

```
plan = Plan.find(params[:subscription][:plan_id])
```

As in your params you have the `plan_id` inside `subscription`:

```
Parameters: {"subscription"=>{"company"=>"", "adress"=>"", "city"=>"", "country"=>"", "postal_code"=>"", "phone"=>"", "plan_id"=>"52", "stripe_card_token"=>""}}
```

Hope this helps.